# "Where" or "in which"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, nouns

> I offer 2 and a half years of programming with Python where I’ve become familiarized with packages such as matplotlib and seaborn, among others.

I included 'where' but I think that refers to a place. Not time.

Am I using it correctly?

Comment: to learn is better than become familiar with. And you can use which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest changing "*I offer two and half years of programming*" to "*I offer two and half years of experience programming*": the first makes it sound like you are planning to program for the addressee for two and half years and not more or less.

As for your question: yes, 'where' refers to a location. Taking my correction into account, you can use 'during which', which refers to that two and half year period:

> I offer two and a half years of experience programming with Python, **during which** I’ve familiarized myself with packages such as matplotlib and seaborn, among others.

"*I’ve become familiarized*" should either be "*I've become familiar*" or "*I've familiarized myself*".

Comment: Insane! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

'Where' does not need to have locative or directional reference:

> **where** [conjunction] ...
>
> 2b: at or in which
>
> - *two fireplaces where you can bake bread in the ovens* — Randall Jarrell
> - *has reached the size where traffic is a problem*

[[Merriam-Webster; adjusted slightly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/where)].

So it would not be drastically wrong here. However, I'd go with @Joachim's suggestion to switch to 'experience [in] programming'. I'd also switch to 'during which time' to match the 'two and half years' (or just write a separate sentence:

- *I offer two and a half years of experience programming with Python. I’ve familiarized myself with packages such as Matplotlib and Seaborn.*)

Note that 'such as ... among others' is suboptimal.